# git workflow confusion using git command

Tags: git, github

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout origin master
$ git checkout -b <branch-name>
$ git add <files>
$ git commit <files> -m <commit-message>
$ git push -u origin <branch-name>
```

Is this good flow of collaboration using git between members? what doesn't no.1 and 3 do? I usually just do pull.

Comment: A fetch won't merge any of the changes in to your local branches.  You still have to pull or you'll steadily get out of sync with origin.

Answer (score 0):

As @Makoto mentioned, you probably intended to bring the changes from the remote `master` into your local version of that branch.  You are currently not doing this, because you never merge or rebase the local branch on the remote tracking branch.  You can try this workflow instead:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout -b <branch-name>
# etc.
```

or if you want to explicitly fetch:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git merge origin/master
git checkout -b <branch-name>
# etc.
```